# Excel VBA triggering multiple events independently with dynamic scroll bars

Tags: excel, vba, triggers, scrollbar

I have an excel workbook with three dynamic scroll bars in one tab of a workbook. I need to dynamically adjust the "max" value of the scroll bar based on the total lines of data in the source table. I have tried using the following code to achieve this; however this is adjusting the Max for all three scroll bars based on the value in cell S49, rather than separately adjusting Scrollbar 1, 2, and 3, based on the values in S49, S66, and S83, respectively:

```
Private Sub ScrollBar1_Change()
ActiveSheet.ScrollBar1.Max = Range("S49").Value

ActiveSheet.ScrollBar2.Max = Range("S66").Value

ActiveSheet.ScrollBar3.Max = Range("S83").Value


End Sub
```

How would I go about modifying this code in order to independently trigger the max value of each scroll bar based on a change in these cells?

Comment: If you want max to be adjusted with cell change, you can use the Worksheet_Change event. `If Not (Intersect(Target, Range("S49")) is Nothing Then` would let you only look for changes on S49.

Comment: I am not sure this would work, as I need each scrollbar maximum to be adjusted based on the value of the reference cell. So Scrollbar1 maximum changes when there is a change in cell S49, Scrollbar2 maximum changes when there is a change in cell S66, and Scrollbar3 maximum changes when there is a change in cell S83.

Comment: You add 3 if...then statements inside worksheet_change event, one for each (range/cell).